# MarkdownPad preview fails on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

MarkdownPad preview is failing with

> Awesomium web-browser framework this view has crashed

[image: markdownpad failure]

The machine was once Windows 8.1 but has since been upgraded to Windows 10. MarkdownPad failed when the machine was 8.1 too.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

They answer it in the [FAQ](http://markdownpad.com/faq.html#livepreview-directx) but it is easy to miss because it is specifically for Windows 8 and not clearly written.

The fix is to install [Awesomium 1.6.6 SDK](http://markdownpad.com/download/awesomium_v1.6.6_sdk_win.exe)

Comment: Thanks, I wish they'd update the installer to fix this issue.

Comment: be fair installing 110 MB SDK just to make editor work??

Comment: Also note that the latest version of Awesomium doesn't work with MarkdownPad. Version 1.6.6 is fine.

Comment: @Mahesha999 Yep, 110MB is way easier than having everyone's app crash and then having to find this solution.

Comment: Latest version of [Awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com/download) (1.7.5.1) does **not** work. So, it has to be version 1.6.6

Comment: This article https://chaohershi.github.io/MarkdownPad-Crash-And-Error-Fix/ helped me with this issue, and also with the subsequent GitHub markdown rendering SSL/TLS connection error.